# Change name of @CollectionTable in each derived

Tags: hibernate

I have Base class which contains an Id property and a base collection properties, i.e. `Map<String, String>`. I am using `@ElementCollection`and`@CollectionTable. getProperties()` method is in Base which is overridden in two derived classes, I would like to change the a `@CollectionTable(name = "Derived1")` for Derived1 and accordingly for Derived 2. But it gives me type could not determine exception.

Can